# Reflection in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this class:

```
public class UserFilter
{
    public bool IsShowCars { get; set; } = true;

    public bool IsShowBikes { get; set; } = true;

    public bool IsShowMotorcycles { get; set; } = true;

    public bool IsShowTrucks { get; set; } = false;

    public bool IsShowPlanes { get; set; } = true;

    public bool IsShowTrains { get; set; } = true;
}
```

And I want to create a checkbox in my .cshtml view file, using CheckBoxFor and a LabelFor, for each property in the class, in order to bind them to the Model.
Is there any way of doing that with a Foreach loop, without literally typing each of them like `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Filter.IsToShowCars)`?

Comment: As far as I remember `CheckBoxFor` accepts something like   `Expression<Func<TModel,bool>>`, so you can build corresponding expression tree manually in a loop. But I would argue that in this case it not worth the time.

Comment: You can convert your class to <string, boolean>[] and use a foreach loop, but I don't think you will gain a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a `IDictionary<string, bool>` in a loop to checkboxes.

```cs
public class UserFilter
{
    public bool IsShowCars { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsShowBikes { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsShowMotorcycles { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsShowTrucks { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsShowPlanes { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsShowTrains { get; set; } = true;
        
    public IDictionary<string, bool> ToCheckList() 
    {
        // Convert your model to 
        // a 'loopable' collection
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
        var dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, bool>>(json);
        return dict;
    }

    public static UserFilter FromCheckList(IDictionary<string, bool> dict) 
    {
        // Convert the collection
        // back to your model
        // Attention: this creates a new object!
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserFilter>(json);
    }
}
```

Eventually you can change it to fill the existing properties in `FromCheckList` to the current instance.

Working example can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HiMdr3)

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement,you could try as below in your view to construct the expression:

```
    @model UserFilter
        @using System.Linq.Expressions;
        
        
        @foreach (var prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
    {
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(UserFilter), "x");
        MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, prop.Name);
        Expression<Func<UserFilter, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<UserFilter, bool>>(memberExpression, new ParameterExpression[1] { parameterExpression });
        @Html.LabelFor(expression)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(expression)
    }
}
```

The Result:

[image]