# How to dynamically set model type on ASP.NET Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have the following database context class:

```cs
public partial class MainDB_Context : DbContext
{
    public MainDB_Context()
    {
    }

    public MainDB_Context(DbContextOptions<MainDB_Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Chosen> Chosens { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<BtnMsg> BtnMsgs { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<GameRoster> GameRosters { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and this generic page model:

```cs
public class Admin_IndexModel<T> : PageModel where T : class
{
    readonly MainDB_Context dbContext;

    readonly List<string> DbSetNames;

    readonly DbSet<T> DbSet;
    readonly List<PropertyInfo> DbSetPropInfo;
    readonly List<string> DbSetPKeys;

    public List<T> AsyncDbSetItems;
    ...
    
}
```

I want to create a single Razor page that will show tables from the database, for example for these URLs:

```
/Admin/Chosen
/Admin/BtnMsg
/Admin/GameRoster
```

I want `@model` type to be respectively:

```
Admin_IndexModel<Chosen>
Admin_IndexModel<BtnMsg>
Admin_IndexModel<GameRoster>
```

this is my current Razor page:

```cs
@page "{DbSetName?}"

@using System.Reflection;

@using asp_net_sql.Models
@using asp_net_sql.Pages
@model Admin_IndexModel<Chosen>

@{
    var DbSetNames = ViewData["DbSetNames"] as List<string>;
    var DbSetPropInfo = ViewData["DbSetPropInfo"] as List<PropertyInfo>;
    ...
}

<menu id="adminMenu">
    @foreach (var menuItem in DbSetNames)
    {
        <div class="menu">@menuItem</div>
    }
</menu>

<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var pInf in DbSetPropInfo)
                {
                    <th>@pInf.Name</th>
                }
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                foreach (var item in Model.AsyncDbSetItems)
                {
                    row++;
                    var btnId = $"btn_{row}";
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var pInf in DbSetPropInfo)
                    {
                        var inpId = $"inp_{pInf.Name}_{row}";
                        <td>
                            <input id="@inpId" type="text" value="@pInf.GetValue(item)" />
                        </td>
                    }
                        <td>
                            <button id="@btnId"
                                    type="submit"
                                    asp-page-handler="Update">
                                Change (Post)
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

how do I create expression for @model dynamically using `DbSetName`?

I don't have Views or Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

`@model` expects a certain type,`@model Admin_IndexModel<T>` is not supported,here's an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735903/using-a-generic-model-in-asp-net-mvc-razor) related  in asp.net mvc

For  Asp.net Core Razor Pages,if you want to avoid avoid code duplication,you could create different [partial views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-8.0)(Razor View not Razor Page )

A minimal example:

```
public class MyPageModel : PageModel
{


    [BindProperty(SupportsGet =true)]
    public string? Entity { get; set; }

    public List<BtnMsgs> btnMsgs { get; set; } = default!;

    public List<BtnMsgs> Chosen { get; set; } = default!;

    public List<BtnMsgs> GameRosters { get; set; } = default!;

    public void OnGet()
    {
       //read target entities from db

    }
}
```

Page:

```
@page "/Admin/{Entity}"
@model MyPageModel
@{

}

@if (some condition)
{
    <partial name="@Model.Entity" model="the entities you read from db"></partial>
}
// other conditions
....
```

And you could try with [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/) to reduce the codes in your partial view,I once tried a sample in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976827/reflection-in-net-core/74979431#74979431)